# In a fluid template, how to output the linked file's size?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-4.5

In a fluid template, I would like to output a linked file's size.

I'm using f:link.page to link to the file, as I think this is the way to do it (please correct if not).

```
<f:link.page class="download" pageUid="fileadmin/redaktion/download/papers/{paper.download}" {paper.author}">PDF</f:link.page>
```

As I'm already using the extension ml_links on the site, I thought I could pass the link through lib.parseFunc_RTE, but

```
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc_RTE"><f:link.page class="download" pageUid="fileadmin/redaktion/download/papers/{paper.download}" {paper.author}">PDF</f:link.page></f:format.html>
```

just wraps it into p.bodytext.

Do I have to use a different syntax to apply f:format.html TO f:link.page - or is there a better way to do it (via a fluid or vhs viewhelper)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i use fluidcontent i have vhs extension installed aswell and then just use:

```
<f:format.bytes decimals="1">{v:media.size(path: '{file}')}</f:format.bytes>
```

This outputs clean readable sizes like "28.2 MB".

Answer (score 2):

Actually custom VH is fastest way to achieve that, i.e. basing [on this VH](http://forge.typo3.org/attachments/5577/FilesizeViewHelper.php), you'll need to replace `size` param with a file path, and then use i.e. `filesize` function of PHP to fetch the size in bytes.

Comment: Got it! Note: there's a bug in the VH you mentioned, see last comment on http://forge.typo3.org/issues/8779. I'm posting my VH below.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my VH:

https://gist.github.com/ursbraem/9645542

I've simplified the original a little, outputting "KiB" for file size is too technical for me.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use native TYPO3 FAL parameter **originalFile.size** :

```
{audio.0.originalFile.size -> f:format.bytes()}
```

Comment: Amazing. This works flawlessly

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VHS you may consider https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Media/SizeViewHelper.html (in combination with `f:format.bytes`).

Answer (score 0):

In newer TYPO3 versions you can use the `originalResource.size` attribute of a FileReference object.

```
{file.originalResource.size -> f:format.bytes()}
```

or in your case:

```
{paper.download.originalResource.size -> f:format.bytes()}
```

Answer (score 0):

### TYPO3 10

I needed a file size output for a DCE module in TYPO3 10, this is what I came up with, using VHS:

```
<f:format.bytes><v:media.size><v:format.trim characters="/"><f:uri.typolink parameter="{item.link}" /></v:format.trim></v:media.size></f:format.bytes>
```

**Explained:**

- `f:uri.typolink` generates the full path I need for `v:media.size`
- `v:media.size` requires the path without a leading slash, `v:format.trim` removes this character.
- `f:format.bytes` displays the output from `v:media.size` in KB or MB.